# How do you go about proving the following identity regarding derivatives?

Tags: derivatives, proof-explanation

Here is the offending identity in question which I'm sure has popped up at least a few times in high school textbooks in the past:
$$\left(\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\right)=-\left(\frac{d^2x}{dy^2}\right)\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^3$$
Now the answer key regarding this question begins with $y=f(x)$ and differentiates both sides with respect to "y", giving the well-known: $$\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)\left(\frac{dx}{dy}\right)=1$$ However, the next line in the working jumps to the seemingly unrelated: $$0=(\left(\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\right)\frac{dx}{dy})\frac{dx}{dy}+\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{d^2x}{dy^2}$$ Everything else past that line is logical and sound to me save this one particularly strange jump. Can someone explain how one derives the third equation from the second?

Answer (score 1):

You differentiate both sides of the second equation with respect to $y$. The right hand side becomes 0 and on the left hand side you apply the chain rule.

Comment: ... and the product rule, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

let $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=t$

$\dfrac{dx}{dy}=\dfrac 1t$

$\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\dfrac{-1}{t}$

Can you do it from here?